# How to get the value from sum(columns) function for a specific row PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model, controller

I'm trying to pull values from two columns based from an id. I have the following data in MySQL:

```
id | Rental | Rentals_Out
 1     11         11
```

I want to add both of those two columns in id 1. I've tried searching here and Google, but I haven't quite found what I'm looking for.

Below is the code I'm using

```
$sum_column = DB::select("SELECT SUM(Rental + Rentals_Out) as total_gowns FROM tbl_products WHERE id = '1'");
```

Or I don't mind using Eloquent but how do I enter multiple columns under pluck function? It seems to only work for one column, and I don't want to duplicate the code.

```
$sum_column = UCPost::where('id', 1)->pluck('Rental')->sum();
```

The code works under the raw SQL statement, but the output comes out as the following:

```
[{"total_gowns ":"22"}]
```

How do I get just the value i.e. 22?

Comment: Remove the word SUM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
DB::table('tbl_products')
   ->select(DB::raw('Rental + Rentals_Out as total_gowns'))
   ->where('id', 1)
   ->first()->total_gowns;
```